# WPF Data Validation? Anything out there better than IDataErrorInfo?

Tags: wpf, validation, mvvm, idataerrorinfo

Is there a preferred practice to do Data Validation from within your ViewModel?

Looking into it some people seem to prefer `IDataErrorInfo` and some prefer to roll out their own validation frameworks (http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/wpf_custom_validation.aspx)?

I'm wondering what the "Best Practice" is for Data Validation? Is there something that is accepted by the community when it comes to adhering to the M-V-VM guidelines?

Oh, and an FYI, I'm using Prism as my MVVM framework, but I don't think it has any laid out code for Validation assistance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might use the [**Validation Framework**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) of the .NET Framework. It can be used with PRISM or any other MVVM Framework. The **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)** shows how to use it together with WPF Binding.